# Difference between okhttp and httpurlconnection?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, okhttp

What are the differences between these 2 libraries?

How I understood there is a difference between these 2 lib also because Volley uses httpurlconnection and Retrofit the okhttp....

But I don't understand the difference between them and pros and cons of both solutions. When is okhttp better and when httpurlconnection?

I would like to know so I know when should I use them.

EDIT:

Why does android use okhttp for the httpurlconnection? before httpurlconnection was not using okhttp if I am not wrong

Comment: The history of the projects are explained here: http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/46/

Answer (score 11):

**Pros of okHttp**
OkHttp can be customized for every request easily — like timeout customization, etc. for each request.
**OkHttp** perseveres when the network is troublesome: it will silently recover from common connection problems. If your service has multiple IP addresses OkHttp will attempt alternate addresses if the first connect fails.

**Complete analytics** of any request can be obtained. You can know bytes sent, bytes received, and the time taken on any request. These analytics are important so that you can find the data usage of your application and the time taken for each request, so you can identify slow requests.

Using OkHttp is easy. Its request/response API is designed with fluent builders and immutability. It supports both synchronous blocking calls and async calls with callbacks.

OkHttp supports Android 2.3 and above. For Java, the minimum requirement is 1.7.

Comment: Is this something that cannot be achieved with HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: the Redirections

Answer (score 7):

### **HttpURLConnection**

**Advantages:**

- Lightweight APIs help in easier management and reduces compatibility issues.
- Automatic handling of the caching mechanisms, with the help of
  HttpResponseCache.
- Reduces the network usage and also, the battery consumption.

**Query Parameter:**

```
    URI baseUri = new URI("www.exemple.com/search");
URI uri = applyParameters(baseUri, "word","java");
HttpURLConnection connection = 
    (HttpURLConnection) uri.toURL().openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
if (connection.getResponseCode() == 
   HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
   // ...
}
```

**Android Headers Example:**

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("CustomHeader", token);
```

### **OkHttp**

**Advantages:**

- Connection pooling
- Gziping
- Caching
- Recovering from network problems
- Redirects
- Retries
- Support for synchronous and asynchronous calls

**Query Parameter:**

```
HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://httpbin.org/get").newBuilder();
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("website", "www.journaldev.com");
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("tutorials", "android");
String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
                     .url(url)
                     .build();
```

**Android Headers Example:**

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .header("Authorization", "replace this text with your token")
    .url("your api url")
    .build();
```

Comment: How can I do this in Retrofit

Answer (score 3):

The API's are different, personally I prefer the OkHttp ones.

Note that starting from Android 4.4, the networking layer (so also the HttpUrlConnection APIs) is implemented through OkHttp.

Comment: thanks Marco, but I would like to know also the differences and the use cases... I don't understand the difference between them. So from Android 4.4 the net layer is OkHttp? and what about the httpurlconnection then?

Comment: HTTPURLConnection is a wrapper over OkHttp and conforms to the java HTTPURLConnection spec