# Is there any advantage to using HttpURLConnection over Okhttp3?

Tags: android, kotlin, httpurlconnection, okhttp

I'm pulling down a simple xml file from the internet and feeding it through `XmlPullParser`.  I'd been using `HttpURLConnection` which seems to work fine, but then I started playing around with `OkhttpClient` so now I'm wondering if/when it's a better to use `HttpUrlConnection`.  `Okhttp` implementation certainly feels cleaner.

```
// For Example
@Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
suspend fun fetchRss(): List<RssItem> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            var rssList: List<RssItem> = emptyList()

            try {

                val url = URL(RSS)
                val connection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

                connection.apply {
                    readTimeout = 10000 // in millis
                    connectTimeout = 15000
                    requestMethod = "GET"
                    connect()
                }

                val input: InputStream = connection.inputStream
                rssList = parseRss(input) as ArrayList<RssItem>
                input.close()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return@withContext rssList
        }

@Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
suspend fun fetchRssWithOkhttp(): List<RssItem> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(RSS).build()
        var rssList: List<RssItem> = emptyList()

        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
                if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

                rssList = parseRss(response.body()!!.byteStream())
                response.close()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return@withContext rssList
    }
```

Comment: This will answer your question my friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953923/relation-between-okhttp-and-httpurlconnection    AND   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571780/difference-between-okhttp-and-httpurlconnection